# Passing data between two controllers MVC

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and I have two different controllers - login.php and site.php

In login.php

```
function credentials(){
    $user = $this->input->post('username');
    // there is some code here
}
```

In site.php, I have **function members_area()**  I need to pass the variable $user from login.php to site.php. How do I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: And who calls `credential()` method?

Comment: If you're sticking to Codeigniter's flavor of MVC, you probably shouldn't be sharing between controllers. Consider using a library or helper for handling shared information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about user logins here.. In your `Login` controller you verify user credentials. If so then you need to set a session variable

```
$this->sessions->set_userdata('user_id',$user_id);
redirect('site/members_area');
```

Then in your `Site` controller you retrieve the data for that user from DB.

```
$current_user = $this->sessions->userdata('user_id');
```

And you get your required data from DB.

Comment: I did the same thing. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

just take a redirect to site/members_area/$user
and you'll get $user parameter in the function members_area($user)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that a controller is used to control what is sent to a view. If the design is right you're not really supposed to send data between two controllers.

I sent inserted the value of username into a session.

So, In login.php

```
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

and retrieved the value in site.php

```
$data['userid'] =  $this->session->userdata('username');
$this->load->view('members_area' , $data); //send the info to the controller
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want some common functions in two controller put it in a helper file

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/55212/